# Any way to keep watched list always open in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Every time the debug jumps into a new method, it closes my list. The list was a private field in the object, but I also tried adding it as a watched variable. No success, every jump also closes that.

Am I missing something or is this just not a feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [IDEA-125550](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125550), not yet fixed, please vote